# NHibernate relationships with a shared composite key

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have two tables with composite keys and a linking table between them, like so:

- A

  - aid (PK)
  - sharedkey (PK)
- B

  - bid (PK)
  - sharedkey (PK)
- Linking

  - aid
  - bid
  - sharedkey
  - sortorder

So the awkward thing there is the shared key, which is part of both FKs. Here's the first thing I tried (I'm using Fluent, but I would have this same problem with XML mappings):

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Bees)
    .Table("Linking")
    .ParentKeyColumns.Add("aid", "sharedkey")
    .ChildKeyColumns.Add("bid", "sharedkey")
    .OrderBy("sortorder");
```

Which gives me an mapping exception: "Repeated column in mapping for collection", because I've put in `sharedkey` twice. That makes sense, because I haven't told in NH that I actually want `sharedkey` to be the same in each direction.

The Java version of Hibernate has a `formula` [feature](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-composite-key-manytomany) that solves this exactly, but NH, AFAIK, does not. So how can I map this?

Some caveats:

1. It's not totally necessary for this to be in Fluent. XML is fine too
2. This is all read-only, so if the solution breaks inserts in some funny way, that's fine
3. I can't change the DB at all

Comment: If you can create a view in the database, then you can create a wrapping view that exposes the sharedkey column as two different columns, then map to that view.

Comment: @eulerfx - yup, thought of that already--I should have mentioned it in the question--and it does work. I'd strongly prefer to avoid it though, because there are tons of these linking tables, which means tons of views (but just one piece of fluent code). It is nice to know I have it as a fallback, though.

Answer (score 1):

a hackish solution could be

```
public AMap()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "aid")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Name, "sharedkey");

    HasManyToMany(x => x.Bees)
        .Table("Linking")
        .ParentKeyColumns.Add("aid", "sharedkey")
        .ChildKeyColumn("bid").ChildPropertyRef("Id")
        .OrderBy("sortorder")
        ;
}

public BMap()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "bid")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Name, "sharedkey");

    Map(x => x.Id, "bid")
        .Not.Insert();
}
```

to get all B's this will result in (pseudo sql):

```
SELECT l.bid FROM a LEFT JOIN linking l ON a.aid = l.aid AND a.sharedkey = l.sharedkey WHERE a.aid = ?
```

this will get all B with the given aid and the same sharedkey.

Comment: I don't quite follow that - what makes sure that Bees I end up with have the right sharedkey?

Comment: AMap says that shardkey is in A's Key so when it queries the link-table it has to filter for A (aid and shardkey) and B (bid). since A's sharedkey and B's sharedkey are the same its enough to filter sharedkey only for A.

Comment: Right, that gets me the right row of the linking table. But I have to get all the way to B such that b.id=l.bid and b.sharedkey=a.sharedkey [or l.sharedkey, same thing]. There can be other rows in B with the bid and different sharedkeys. But maybe I'm totally missing something.

Comment: @Isaac Cambron oh right i missed that. The very dirty workaround for that could be `.ChildWhere("bees0_.sharedkey = sharedkey")` where `bees0_` will be the standard nhibernate alias created from the name of the collection Property suffixed with `0_`.